# How to make a 1s second pause inside a forEach loop reading a firebase file?

Tags: javascript, loops, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the follow javascript function that reads data from firebase inside an each loop.

I am using it to plot the data in a google map trough its API.

I would like to know how to make a 1second pause between each round of the loop.

```js
var markers = [];
var mapObject;
var z = 0;
var myLatLngA = [];

$(function() {
  firebase.database().ref('clicks').on('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(item) {
      var objc = {
        lat: item.val().lat,
        lng: item.val().lng
      };
      myLatLngA.push(objc);
      //setMapOnAll(null);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLngA[z],
        map: mapObject
      });
      markers.push(marker);
      marker.setMap(mapObject);
      z++;
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Set timeout can be used or what?

Comment: I can't see how to use setInterval or setTimeout since this approach would connect the databse at each 1second. This is not what I want. What I need is to move the loop pointer to the next data after 1 second.

Comment: I mean inside for each callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just delay the appearance of the markers.

```
$(function() {
  firebase.database().ref('clicks').on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var func = function(item) {
      var objc = {
        lat: item.val().lat,
        lng: item.val().lng
      };
      myLatLngA.push(objc);
      //setMapOnAll(null);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLngA[z],
        map: mapObject
      });
      markers.push(marker);
      marker.setMap(mapObject);
      z++;
    }
    var i = 0;
    snapshot.forEach(function(item) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            func(item)
        }), i++ * 1000);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i get it very well, but you can use setTimeout() between every iteration of the forEach. 
**ES6 syntax**

```
let  markers = [];let mapObject;let z = 0;let myLatLngA = [];

$(function() {
  firebase.database().ref('clicks').on('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(item) {
      settimeout(()=>{
        var objc = {
          lat: item.val().lat,
          lng: item.val().lng
        };
        myLatLngA.push(objc);
        //setMapOnAll(null);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLngA[z],
          map: mapObject
        });
        markers.push(marker);
        marker.setMap(mapObject);
        z++;
      }, 1000);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi Yuri that approach gave me back all data at once. I should have 1 row per second.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Wrap your loop code in a setTimeout:</s>

```
$(function () {
    firebase.database().ref('clicks').on('value', function (snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function (item) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var objc = {
                    lat: item.val().lat,
                    lng: item.val().lng
                };
                myLatLngA.push(objc);
                //setMapOnAll(null);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatLngA[z],
                    map: mapObject
                });
                markers.push(marker);
                marker.setMap(mapObject);
                z++;
            }, 1000); // 1 second
        });
    });
});
```

Use RxJs observables, so something like:

```
let markers = [];
let mapObject;
let z = 0;
let myLatLngA = [];

$(function () {
    const clickValueObserver = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(firebase.database().ref('clicks'), 'value')
        .map(snapshot => Rx.Observable.from(snapshot)
            .concatMap(item => Rx.Observable.timer(1000) // every 1 second
                .mapTo(item)))
        .concatAll();


    clickValueObserver.subscribe(item => {
        let objc = {
            lat: item.val().lat,
            lng: item.val().lng
        };
        myLatLngA.push(objc);
        //setMapOnAll(null);
        let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLngA[z],
            map: mapObject
        });
        markers.push(marker);
        marker.setMap(mapObject);
        z++;
    });
});
```

The difficult part was figuring out how to prevent it from stopping midway through processing an event data when a new event arrives yet, keep track of all the events and process them even with the delay in the processing. The `concatX` methods were really the key.

#### Sample: (click X times and observe that the contents of the array is displayed every 1 second, and this is done X times):

```js
const myStuff = Array.from(Array(5).keys());
let clicks = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click')
  .mapTo(Rx.Observable.from(myStuff)
    .concatMap(myVal => Rx.Observable.timer(1000)
      .mapTo(myVal)));
clicks.concatAll().subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.4.0/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

**Ref**: https://gist.github.com/btroncone/d6cf141d6f2c00dc6b35

Comment: Hi smac89 that approach gave me back all data at once. I should have 1 row per second.

Comment: @zwitterion, Check out the observables solution

Answer (score 0):

Push them all, then process them one by one:

```js
var markers = [],
  mapObject, currentMarker = 0,
  myLatLngA = [];

function processMarkers() {
  if (currentMarker >= myLatLngA.length) return; // stop
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLngA[currentMarker],
    map: mapObject
  });
  markers.push(marker);
  marker.setMap(mapObject);
  currentMarker++;
  setTimeout(processMarkers, 1000);
}

$(function() {
  firebase.database().ref('clicks').on('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(item) {
      var objc = {
        lat: item.val().lat,
        lng: item.val().lng
      };
      myLatLngA.push(objc);
    });
    processMarkers();
  });
});
```

Comment: Since firebase is used for a real time exchange, I think this approach is not good because while I am processing a bunch of data, I would have new data to be processed. It would cost time in the process.

Comment: You need debounce